# All the code written in my view also appears in the doc when i export to DOC in php Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3, export-to-word

My Controller Code :

```
   public function export()
   {
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.msword");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control:  must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"Proposal TJSLP (".date('d-m-Y H:i:s').").doc\"");

    $where = array('usulan_id' => $this->uri->segment(4));
    $data['data'] = $this->data_model->export_usulan($where)->result();

    $this->load->view("usulan_export", $data);
   }
```

My View :

```
<?php foreach ($data as $key => $h) { ?>
<center>
<h1>PROPOSAL</h1>
<h3>
    ((Nama Perusahaan)) <br> TAHUN <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <br><br><br>
    <?php echo $h->nama; ?>
</h3>
</center>
<?php } ?>
```

The return is :

[image: The Return]

The export to DOC is works, but all the code written in my view also appears in the doc, like code a "" etc. I just called the picture is not called in the document. Please tell me, how to make the code illegible and appear according to the code we write??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view just add :

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for a library like PHP office: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord - this allows you to create Documents programatically.